# jQuery mobile-display dialog box at the same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile 1.4 to display a dialog box in case there is no data in input field. I have the problem that dialog box is showing in another page and I want it to be at the same page. Also when I click buttoon "x" it goes back at page "item_data.php" and then at "dialog.php". I have created a file "dialog.php" that has:

```
<div data-role="page" data-dialog="true">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1><?php echo $_GET['mesage']; ?></h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h1>Warning</h1> 
        <p>Can't find this location</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and item_data.php

```
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="text-basic">Insert Item Location:</label>
        <input  data-type="search" id="searchField_2" placeholder="Location" data-theme="a">
        <ul id="suggestions_2" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#searchField_2").autocomplete({
            target: $('#suggestions_2'),
            source: 'locations.json',
            callback: function(e) {
                var $a = $(e.currentTarget);
                $('#searchField_2').val($a.text());
                $("#searchField_2").autocomplete('clear');
            },
            minLength: 1,
            matchFromStart: false
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialogs are [deprecated in v1.4 of jQuery mobile](http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/). The API docs mention the [Popup Widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/) as replacement. Basically you just have to set the data-role for your dialog from `page` to `popup`, like so:

```
<div id="locationWarning" data-role="popup" data-theme="b">
    ...
</div>
```

Concerning your reload problem: You have to intercept the submit event for your form and show the popup instead. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/Zp6c7/

```
var $form = $('.formSelector');
var $searchField = $('#searchField_2');

$form.on('submit', function(e){
   if ($searchField.val().length === 0) {
       e.preventDefault();

       $.get('./dialog.php?message="Location not found"', function(response){
            var $popup = $(response);
            var $existing = jQuery('#' + $popup.attr('id'));

            if ($existing.length > 0) {
              $existing.replaceWith($popup);
            } else {
              $('body').append($popup);
            }

            $popup.popup();
            $popup.popup('open');
       });
   }
});
```

Comment: thank you :) but now it's a bug, i need to do e reload in order to display the popup